# Proving a subgroup of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question states, Let H be subgroup of a group G. Prove that HH=H and that $H^{-1}=H$ 
 I started the 1st proof by saying 
 HH=H 
 We will show that $HH\subseteq H$ 
 Then $x\in HH$ 
 Then $x=ab$ where $a\in H$ and $b\in H$ 
 I am lost right now trying to prove HH=H and $H^{-1}=H$ 
 Anybody can help me?

Comment: those are my next few steps for the 1st proof?

Comment: I have not got that far yet because I am still trying to prove HH=H first

Comment: would $H^{-1} \subseteq H$?

Comment: Working on a master's degree in mathematics but not being able to solve the above elementary problem should trigger some serious soul searching about becoming a professional mathematician.

Comment: some professors didnt teach me proofs when i took undergrad courses so i am behind the 8 ball. i learned a lot since. thanks for the concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already mentioned in my comment that $HH=H$.

We know that $H<G$. We have $$H^{-1}=\{h^{-1}: h\in H\}.$$

Let $x\in H^{-1}$. Then $x=h^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$. Because $H<G$, we have $h^{-1}\in H$. Thus, $x\in H$. Hence, $H^{-1}\subset H$.

Let $y\in H$. Then $y^{-1}\in H$. Hence, $y=(y^{-1})^{-1}\in H^{-1}$. Thus, $H\subset H^{-1}$.

Done.Hope it helps.

Comment: what is the purpose of using Y?

Comment: What? I can't understand. There is no $Y$ in my proof. Rather I used $y$.

Comment: sorry typo. that $y$. what is the purpose of introducing it

Comment: We know that we want to show that $H\subset H^{-1}$. Pick an element in $H$. Its just happened that I denote it by $y$. That's only a name. You can use $x$ if you want.--)

Comment: I did check it. I was the 1st one to do so because I immediately saw that is was right. I just needed a clarification on that $y$

Comment: I put my answer up. Can you check it?

Answer (score 2):

$\forall a \in H \text{ and } b \in H \implies ab=x \in H$ (because $H$ is a group) $\implies HH \subseteq H$. And $\forall x \in H \implies x = 1.x \in HH \implies H \subseteq HH$ (where $1$ denotes the identity element of $H$).

Now, go ahead with the next one similarly!

Comment: This look similar to mines up above. It looks like you stated what I did but in reverse order. So basically my next step is for all $x\in H$ if x=1?

Comment: Not really. Lemme try again. Let $1$ be the identity element of $G$, since $H$ is a subgroup, $1 \in H$. So, we have $x = 1.x = x.1 \forall x \in H$. But, $1.x \in HH \implies x \in HH \implies H \subseteq HH$

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is attempt to answer $HH=H$ 
 We will show that $HH\subseteq H$ 
 Then $x\in HH$ 
 Then $x=ab$ where $a\in H$ and $b\in H$ 
 but $x$ is closed under multiplication 
 so $x\in H$ 
 My professor also wants me show that $HH\subseteq H$ for my first part of this question. For some reason I do not understand. Somebody can help me? 
 Here is my attempt to prove $HH\subseteq H$ 
 $x\in H$ if $x\in HH$
 I am lost after this

Comment: Your proof is not properly constructed.

Comment: On your first part, you already said that $x\in HH$ and so $x=ab$. Since $H$ is closed under multiplication, $ab\in H$. So, $x\in H$. With this, we conclude that $HH\subseteq H$.

Comment: ok. my professor  told me to show $HH=H$ and $HH\subseteq H$. So I am done then

Comment: On your second part, you need to show that $H\subseteq HH$. Choose an $x\in H$. How do we show that $x\in HH$? Well, we should show that $x$ can be expressed as a product of two elements of $H$. The two elements that we are going to choose are $1$ and $x$, where $1$ is the identity element of group $G$ and hence the identity element of $H$. Now, $$x=1\cdot x.$$ Note that $1\cdot x\in HH$ and this shows that indeed, $x\in HH$. And we are done. Hope this helps.

Comment: so after I state $x\in HH$, state what you just said about the identity element of $G$. cool and thanks again

Comment: got you. thanks again

Answer (score -3):

Given   that   H   be   a   sub   group   of   G
So   we   have to   show   that   HH   =   H
For that it is enough to show that HH ⊆ H and H ⊆ HH
Now   let   h_1  h_2∈HH        where   h_1∈ H,   h_2∈ H
∴   h_1∈H ,h_2∈ H   ⇒  h_1  h_2∈H      (  ∵ closed law  )
∴   h_1  h_2 ∈ HH   ⇒   h_1  h_2 ∈ H
⇒   HH⊆ H    ------------ (1)
Again    let   h ∈ H   then   we   have to   show   that   h ∈ HH
Let   h ∈ H   and   e ∈ H   ⇒ he ∈ HH
                                             ⇒ h ∈ HH

∴      h ∈ H  ⇒   h ∈ HH 
                         ⇒  H ⊆ HH   ------------------------- (2)
∴      from   (1)  and  (2)  we  get  HH =  H ( ∵  HH ⊆ H and  H ⊆ HH)
Hence  proved